# (Django Rest Framework) How to add backward URL field?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using drf-nested-routers. Parameter and Location are connected by _location foreign key. Inside Parameter, I want to add a Location field that points to its Location. I think what I need is a backward url link? How could I achieve this?

model

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'locations'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Parameter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    values = models.JSONField(default=list, blank=True)
    _location = models.ForeignKey(Location, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                related_name="parameters"
                )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializer

```
class ParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    aggregation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    #I want to add the location url here
    location = 
    class Meta:
        model = Parameter
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'unit', 'aggregation', 'location', 'values')
    
    def get_aggregation(self, obj):
        return aggregate(obj.values)
    def create(self, obj):
        return add_parameter(obj)

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='weather:location-parameters-list', lookup_url_kwarg='location_pk')
    aggregation = serializers.JSONField(default=dict, source="parameters.aggregation", allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id','name', 'description','longitude', 'latitude', 'aggregation', 'parameters')
    def create(self, obj):
        return add_location(obj)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = "weather"

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('locations', LocationViewSet)

locations_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, 'locations', lookup='location')
locations_router.register('parameters', ParameterViewSet, basename='location-parameters')

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    path("", include(locations_router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers#hyperlinks-for-nested-resources?

Comment: Yes I did. It helps me with my Location parameters field as you can see I used HyperlinkedIdentityField there. But for Parameter, it's different because I want the backward relation.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to do it the manual way by:

```
 request = self.context['request']
 return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('weather:location-detail', 
                                                    args=[obj._location.id]))
```

for anyone that has problem like me. Initially I don't know how to pass context in model since I use ModelViewSet. You could do this and then call `self.context['request']` in your serializer

```
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(ParameterViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```